# Weird overful vbox message when code and image are overlaid in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, overlays, code

See the following code. The first two frame contents (first one code, second one image) do not produce any overfull vbox message.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=XML,
  basicstyle=\small
}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname code.xml}
<document>
  <part>
    <chapter>
      <section>
        <subsection>
          <subsubsection>
            <paragraph>
              text
            </paragraph>
          </subsubsection>
        </subsection>
      </section>
    </chapter>
  </part>
</document>
\end{filecontents}

\def\putcode{\begin{center}\lstinputlisting{\jobname code.xml}\end{center}}
\def\putimage{\begin{center}\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.8\textheight}\end{center}}

\begin{frame}
  \putcode
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \putimage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<+>
    \putcode
    \onslide<+>
    \putcode
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<+>
    \putimage
    \onslide<+>
    \putimage
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<+>
    \putcode
    \onslide<+>
    \putimage
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When you compile the code, you will be able to readily see that, no overfull message is generated when code is overlaid over code, or an image is overlaid over an image.

But for the last overlay, image over code, we get an overfull vbox message (one for each slide).

> `Overfull \vbox (187.1715pt too high) detected at line 68`

While I can decide to ignore the message, that is not sufficient, because the image gets moved upward (by the overfull amount?), in a rather awkward  manner.

I understand that the situation can be remedied by a `\vspace` command or something like that, but I would really like to understand the reason.

Comment: If you make the rule red, the error goes away?!!?

Comment: @cfr Hard to believe, but actually, it does go away. But as you can see, this is only an MWE, where the rule was used as an image. What to do for the case of a real image? Again, I would award the bounty to one who can give me the *inside news*.

Comment: Sure. It wasn't intended as a solution! I just thought it extremely odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when the image is to be placed in the last slide, TeX is in vertical mode; using `\leavevmode` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=XML,
  basicstyle=\small
}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname code.xml}
<document>
  <part>
    <chapter>
      <section>
        <subsection>
          <subsubsection>
            <paragraph>
              text
            </paragraph>
          </subsubsection>
        </subsection>
      </section>
    </chapter>
  </part>
</document>
\end{filecontents}

\def\putcode{\begin{center}\lstinputlisting{\jobname code.xml}\end{center}}
\def\putimage{\begin{center}\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.8\textheight}\end{center}}

\begin{frame}
  \putcode
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \putimage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<+>
    \putcode
    \onslide<+>
    \putcode
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<+>
    \putimage
    \onslide<+>
    \putimage
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<+>
    \putcode
    \onslide<+>
    \leavevmode\putimage
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does the message go away when the box is colored red? Anything to do with vertical mode? See the comments to the question.

Comment: @Masroor Wouldn't `\color{}` put TeX back in horizontal mode?

Comment: And I do not get the point about last slide. This `\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<+>
    \putimage
    \onslide<+>
    \putcode
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}' also produces the error. And why is not the message there for two overlaid slides of the same kind?

Comment: @Masroor Reply to your second comment: again, you will need to leave vertical mode: `\begin{frame} 
\begin{overprint} 
  \onslide<+> 
  \leavevmode\putimage 
  \onslide<+> 
  \putcode 
  \end{overprint} 
\end{frame}`.

Comment: @Masroor Reply to your first comment:  Using `\textcolor` or `\color` right before `\putimage` switches to horizontal mode so the warning disappears.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Just for a little more comprehension, why does not the message appear for two overlaid slides of the same kind, image over image or text over text?

Comment: @cfr no (`\textcolor` would, not `\color`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then why does `\color{red}` avoid the warning? If it is not switching to horizontal mode, then what is the explanation? That is, I did not use `\textcolor{red}` but only `\color{red}`.

Comment: @cfr  at a quarter to 2 in the morning I haven't the faintest idea:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was surprised when I noticed that `\color` will also prevent the problem. Tomorrow I will do a `\tragingall` experiment to see if anything shows up or perhaps you have a clue by now?

Comment: turns out you don't need to get out of vmode, `\hbox{}` or `\write20{hello}` or basically any node at all stops the overfull vbox. I guess it's the `\onslide<+>` code reacting badly to the `center` environment at the start of `\putimage` but `beamer` does what it does....